# Local complete intersection on a smooth variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, complete-intersection

Let $X$ be a smooth variety and let $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k}$ be general points. Let $T:=<T_{x_{1}}X,\ldots,T_{x_{k}}X>$ be the join of the tangent spaces at the points  $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k}$. If we know that $T\cap X$ has only isolated singularities in an open neighborhood of $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k}$, is it true that $T\cap X$ is a local complete intersection?

Comment: You're assuming a specified embedding of $X$ in some projective space, to take the join?